# Are values written by one thread guaranteed to be seen by another thread without locking on that variable?

Tags: c++, multithreading, x86-64

I'm trying to understand the coherency guarantees in C++ on a x86-64 machine, and if that varies on other platforms. Specifically I'm wondering if I can guarantee that if one thread writes to a variable before the next thread reads from it, will I always see the correct value? I've read some conflicting information about this.

Here's an example, where `Shared` is updated in another thread, and the result is read only when we're sure the value is finished being updated. Will this always print 1? It has every time I tested it, but I can't really prove it by example.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>

std::atomic<bool> Done {false};
int Shared = 0;

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    auto Thread = std::thread([](){
        Shared = 1;
        Done = true;
    });

    while(!Done)
    {
    }

    std::cout << Shared << std::endl;

    Thread.join();
    return 0;
}
```

This blog seems to suggest that on x86-64 all writes are made visible to other threads: http://benbowen.blog/post/cmmics_iii/

This document also sounds like it's saying something similar:

> When a thread is writing to a shared memory location, the MESIF protocol requires that all
>   other copies of the memory location is invalidated. If this occurs, all cores in the processor
>   sends a RFO­request (read­for­ownership request) to the LLC (in this case the L3­cache) that
>   checks the snoop­filter and then sends out invalidations to all cache’s that holds a copy of the
>   cache line.

https://www.eit.lth.se/fileadmin/eit/courses/edt621/Rapporter/2015/robin.skafte.pdf

Comment: `Done = true` - *atomic store in thread A* with `memory_order_release` (even stronger) `while(!Done)` - *atomic load in thread B from the same variable is tagged memory_order_acquire* - so [*all memory writes (non-atomic and relaxed atomic) that happened-before the atomic store from the point of view of thread A, become visible side-effects in thread B. That is, once the atomic load is completed, thread B is guaranteed to see everything thread A wrote to memory.*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order#Release-Acquire_ordering)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's complicated, but in your particular case, this is guaranteed to work across all C++ implementations.

The reason is that the default memory order for operations on `std::atomic` is `std::memory_order_seq_cst`, which does guarantee release/acquire semantics.

Specifically, that means that any writes that a thread makes to memory before it release-stores (including sequentially consistent stores, like yours) are visible to any thread that acquire-loads on the same atomic (including sequentially consistent loads, like yours) and observes the new value.

Comment: Even though the _shared_ variable is not atomic? (Just asking to make the answer crystal clear)

Comment: Yes, that's correct. You can use acquire/release memory order semantics to guarantee that changes to memory are visible to other threads, much like you can use a mutex to do so. (Of course, doing so with atomics is much more subtle.)

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but it sounds like you're referring to `Done` and not `Shared`. I'm specifically asking if a variable without locking, or atomic can be updated in one thread and read correctly in another if the ordering is clear as it is here.

Comment: Your use of `std::atomic<bool>` for `Done` here is sufficient to make this correct.

If access to `Done` was not atomic, or was atomic with weaker memory order than `std::memory_order_acq_rel`, then this would be a data race. Any C++ program with a data race has undefined behavior, even on platforms with strong low-level memory order semantics. (In practice, for instance, the compiler may optimize based on incorrect assumptions.)

Comment: Okay I think I get it now, but I feel like I may have just stumbled into writing an example that works. What if the ordering were guaranteed with something other than an atomic? Are there cases where guaranteeing the ordering is insufficient? Specifically I thought there were cases where a value could be updated in one core's cache and not propagated to another?

Comment: You could also use a mutex guarding access to `Done`, which also has the correct semantics (makes all other changes to memory from the thread visible).

There are cases where you can get surprising behavior at the CPU level, but x86 (and x86-64) does happen to offer fairly strong guarantees (so the naive version of this in x86 assembly would behave correctly). Even still, if you're writing C++ code you have to abide by the C++ memory model -- the compiler may not translate code to assembly in the way you expect.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks for your patience explaining Jeremy!

Comment: What about the optimizer?  There is no need to re-read `Shared` on the main thread before outputting it's value.

Comment: Sure there is: it happens-after the acquire-read to `Done` in the while loop condition, therefore failing to re-read `Shared` is an unsound optimization unless the compiler can prove that no thread could have written it before a release-store to `Done` (since such a release-store, as does exist here, would make memory writes, including those to `Shared`, visible side effects after the acquire-load).

Comment: In RISC-V  the ordering semantics are on a per memory location ( ok, really per cache line basis ).  On such an arch, the ordering semantics of Shared and Done are independent, so Shared would become visible because Done did.   Because of widespread expectations, the mutex operations would likely enforce full barriers; but the atomics needn't.

Comment: That was supposed to read Shared would not become visible because Done did.   The standard is ambiguous on whether SC is applied globally ( all memory locations ) or locally ( just the ones affected by the operations ).   I suspect the latter, since they left no invention to utilize more granular memory protocols.

Comment: I'm not familiar with RISC-V, but presumably a C++ compiler targeting such an architecture would need to introduce whatever memory barriers are required to enforce the C++ memory model, which does require writes to become visible after an appropriate acquire-load following a release-store.

Comment: I get the impression that the C++ default memory model is meant to make everything behave like `x86-64` (by inserting these barriers on platforms that would behave differently by default) unless specifically told to use weaker guarantees by specifying `memory_order` is that a fair impression?

Comment: Certainly not as it applies to non-atomic memory accesses. A read with an x86-64 `mov` instruction will be atomic and sequentially consistent (as I understand it); a memory access at the C++ level may not even compile into any instructions at all if the compiler can reason that it has seen the most recent non-data-race write to the memory (and there's nothing else to synchronize).